# How to add functionality in fragment java file to share button I created in home fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I have added a floating share button in `home_fragment.xml`. But I don't know where to start on how to add functionality to that share button. Please help.

This is the code of fragment java file, I have tried do coding but I failed, I'll be glad if anyone can help.

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {
            Button share_bt;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView= inflater.inflate(fragment_home, container, false);

        FloatingActionButton share_bt= rootView.findViewById(R.id.share_bt);
        share_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                myIntent.setType("text/plain");
                String shareBody = "hu" ;
                String shareSub = "mk";
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,shareBody);
                myIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,shareSub);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(myIntent, "Share Using"));
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a View.OnClickListener to invoke a callback method when the button is clicked. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener for more information.

Like @kAliert already answered, you have to get an instance of the View firstand there have been plenty of similiar qustions and answers that could've helped.

Apologies in advance for any styling or grammar mistakes

Here is an example of how to do this in a Fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View homeFragmentView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    FloatingActionButton animationDetailShare= homeFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.animation_detail_share);

    btnCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //The logic for the button
        }
    });

    return homeFragmentView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get an instance of your view and find the button. It isn´t that hard and i guess its answered plenty of times already.